# How to handle request-in-flight case to show loader using redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my redux-saga app, multiple api calls can happen simultaneously, and thus individual loaders and api response success/error messages need to be shown.

How to handle such scenarios?

For example, the following redux state is generally maintained:

```
{
 data : {},
 isError: false,
 isLoading: true
}
```

Here `isLoading` flag changes to true when api call is awaiting response.

`isError` flag turns true when api response returns error.

`data` stores successful response from api

The above approach works fine when simultaneous api calls don't happen.

How to handle the case when simultaneous different api calls are happening?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of scenario :

Instead of using state globally

```
{
 data : {},
 isError: false,
 isLoading: true
}
```

We can use state individually

like in each different api call we can use different reducers and that different reducers we can set  isError and isLoading individually.

Now in rootReducer we are assigning our all reducers in different-different way like responseOfApi1 , responseOfApi2 , etc and  we can access it like props.responseOfApi1,props.responseOfApi2 in our component.

Now we can define isLoading as state in individual component and check if any props.responseOfApi1.isLoading || props.responseOfApi2.isLoading then we can setState({isLoading : true }) and if props.responseOfApi1.isLoading && props.responseOfApi2.isLoading setState({isLoading : false })

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: I found this article -> https://medium.com/stashaway-engineering/react-redux-tips-better-way-to-handle-loading-flags-in-your-reducers-afda42a804c6 to be quite helpful.

Comment: ya for different api calls you can create different reducers with isLoading/isFetching and then you can use response in your component.